# Remove 'label__' from prototype name

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form like this:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('formats', 'collection', array(
        'type'         => new FormatType(),
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'prototype_name' => 'remove'
    ))
    ->add('papers', 'collection', array(
        'type'         => new PaperType(),
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'prototype_name' => 'remove'
    ))
;
```

As you can see I changed the `prototype_name` to `remove`.

Originally it looks like this:
[image]

When I click on the plus sign I get this:
[image]

As you can see the `remove` text is added. But also label__* . How can I fix this that the label__* text isn't added or displayed?

Comment: Why do you use the `prototype_name` option?

Comment: I was trying to change the label ..

Comment: [`prototype-name`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#prototype-name) doesn't seem to be the right option. Did you tried to use [`label => ''`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#label)?

Comment: Then I get __name__label__ instead of removelabel_

Comment: How do you display the form?

Answer (score 0):

Use `'label_attr' => ['style' => 'display: none']`

```
$formMapper
    ->add('formats', 'collection', array(
        'type'         => new FormatType(),
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'label_attr' => ['style' => 'display: none']
    ))
    ->add('papers', 'collection', array(
        'type'         => new PaperType(),
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'label_attr' => ['style' => 'display: none']
    ))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->add('appointment', CollectionType::class,[
            'label' => false,
            'entry_type' => AppointmentType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => false,
            'prototype' => true,
        ])
```

this is my collection for add appointments see the entry_options